# Can you damage the Banshee when she is teleporting?

Tags: mass-effect-3

["How do I stop that banshee from eating my face?"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/54549/1770) provided good strategies for dealing with Reaper Banshees. However I am curious if you can damage the Banshee when she is teleporting.

Comment: One of the tip screens says to attack her while she's charging, so I'd assume yes...

Comment: its possible to shoot at her while she's teleporting, but the blink will cause any floating spells (like inferno or warp) to miss, so you'll have to judge your timing for those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think so, based on most of my encounters....

Answer (score 1):

No, but you can keep her from teleporting if you stay close enough. If she isn't distracted by your squad mates, then she will focus on you and if you stay just about outisde of melee range, she shouldn't teleport around at all. This is from personal experience.

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no. While she's flicking from one position to the other you can't hit her but when she pauses to change direction or continue, that's your time to strike.

They don't teleport as much once you drop their barriers, repeater weapons such as the assault rifle and SMG will make short work of the purple bar. Warp Ammo and some biotic abilities also will make quick work of it.

Once the shields are down, switch to hard hitting anti armor weapons and put the freak down for good.

Keeping in medium range where her shockwave and biotic warp could effect you if you weren't in cover is about where she'll stop teleporting.